# how can I change select options inside table repeater Laravel Filament

Tags: php, laravel-filament, filamentphp

how can I change select options inside the table repeater where this repeater is inside another filament repeater?

like :

```
FilamentFormRepeater::make()->schema([
    //Some Form Elements
    FilamentTableRepeater::make()->schema([
           //Some Form Elements
    ])
])
```

Now I want to change the select element options inside FilamentTableRepeater when a select option changed in FilamentFormRepeater.